# How to prove that a function has a maximum and a minimum

Tags: calculus, intuition

Consider the function $f(x, y) = \sqrt{xy}$ on the domain:
$$D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 2, x \geq 0, y \geq 0\}$$

How would you explain that this function has a maximum and minimum point without having to do any calculations? I found it hard to explain this since the function doesn't have an interval and the values of x and y both go to ∞

Comment: First: make a picture of the set $D$! You will see that $x$ and $y$ can *not* run off to infinity (unless you mistyped and there is a minus sign instead of a plus in the defintion of $D$)

Comment: That said: in general I think this ("explain that [continuous] function has a maximum and minimum point [on certain types of domain] without having to do any calculations") is a good question. There is a beautiful mathematical theory behind that phenomenon.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ can't go to infinity.  $D$ is a quarter circle and $0\le x \le \sqrt 2$ and $0 \le y \le \sqrt 2$ and $y =\sqrt{1-x^2} .  In fact this can be rewritten as $g:[0,\sqrt 2]\to \mathbb R: g(x) = \sqrt {x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and $D$ is compact (it is a closed and bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ must have a maximum and a mnimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\geq \frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$$ And also $$\sqrt{xy}\geq 0$$